# Will Google Analytics code for main domain pages and sub-domain be same?

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

HI Here is my code: Will this code go into all the pages of my website. I know It should go into all pages of the subdomain of my website.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];

  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-*******']);

  **_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'tuneupmedia.com']);**

  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {

    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = 

true;

    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + 

'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

  })();

</script>
```

Comment: Google has 2 different versions of code depending on whether you're using tracking just for the main domain or for subdomains also. Go to the control panel and see.

Comment: I want to track for my sub domain too, therefore I see an additional piece of code that needs to be inserted, which is:  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'tuneupmedia.com']);  , my question is actually ,whether i have to add this piece of code into all the pages of my website too???Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That code should be placed on all your pages, with the same `_setDomainName` value.